# Shell script conditional statement if else does not work

Tags: arrays, macos, shell, if-statement

I am a noob when it comes to the Shell

This block should work, but it doesn't

```
     #!/bin/bash 
     # LOCAL CONFIGURATION SETTINGS - DB_CONFIG is a "fake" associative array
     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     DB_CONFIG=(
        "DB_NAME=>"
        "DB_USER=>root"
        "DB_PASSWORD=>root"
        "DB_HOST=>127.0.0.1"
        "DB_CHARSET=>utf8"
        "DB_COLLATE=>"
     );

     for prop in ${DB_CONFIG[@]} ; do
     key=${prop%%=>*}
     value=${prop##*=>}
     echo $key;
     if[["$key" == "DB_HOST"]] then 
           db_host="$value"

     if[["$key" == "DB_PASSWORD"]] then  
           db_password="$value"

     done;


     # now set the mysql_conn string with the vars above.
     MYSQL_CON="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=$db_host -uroot -$db_password"
     exit;
     REPO='http://svn.wp-plugins.org/'
```

The problem is how to check the condition if `$key == 'DB_HOST'` I just can't figure out the syntax of the expression. I have look into how to do it, but on my mac ( running bash 3.2 ) if complains of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
DB_CONFIG=(
  "DB_NAME=>"
  "DB_USER=>root"
  "DB_PASSWORD=>root"
  "DB_HOST=>127.0.0.1"
  "DB_CHARSET=>utf8"
  "DB_COLLATE=>"
);  

for prop in ${DB_CONFIG[@]}; do
  key=${prop%%=>*}
  value=${prop##*=>}

  if [[ "$key" == "DB_HOST" ]]; then 
       db_host="$value"
  elif [[ "$key" == "DB_PASSWORD" ]]; then  
       db_password="$value"
  fi  
done

echo "$db_host" "$db_password"
```

You were missing the space after `[[` and before `]]`.  You were also missing your `fi` s, which correspond to close brace in C or Java, and are required by bash.  Additionally, if-statements require a `;` after a conditional test.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have leave spaces for `[` and `]` and a `;` before then

```
if [ "$key" == "DB_HOST" ]; then 
      db_host="$value"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an awesome quick reference guide for bash scripting

http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will need to refer to it over the next couple of days.